# Is there way for a web app (WAR file) to "include" the contents of a second web app (WAR file)?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, war

I have Java/Spring/Tomcat web app (webapp1.war) running like so ...

http://server.abc.def:8080/webapp1

Access to the URL is protected by a single sign on controlled by security folks.

I have a second Java/Spring/Tomcat web app (webapp2.war) running like so ...

http://server.abc.def:8080/webapp2

But users can't access it because security won't expose a second URL to users.

QUESTION:

Is there an way to write a JSP (or something else) that can be added to webapp1.war that "includes" webapp2 in such a way that ...

http://server.abc.def:8080/webapp1/webapp2

... will show the new web application?

Comment: For what purpose you are doing this?

Comment: You can include one jsp into another.

Comment: You can include one jsp into another.

Comment: How is the SSO security setup? Does it live/run in Tomcat itself or is it an external app like an F5 or through and Apache or Nginx server?

Comment: @ErikPearson There is an Apache Server fronting the Tomcat server.  Corporate security folks control access to URLs that point to the Apache server.  So if anyone goes to http://servername/webapp1, they are hitting the Apache server and are redirected to login form.  We on the dev team have no control over that.  To get http://servername/webapp2 approved is a long arduous process; easier to just pop the functionality into webapp1 -- but since webapp2 is already written as a standalone app, would like to do a simple "include" somehow.  Thanks!

Comment: @SumeshTG Please see my comment to ErikPearson for more info.

Comment: Create webapp2  folder manually inside webapp1 folder and extract the contents of webapp2 .war to it

Comment: @RobertHume, since they control security through a separate Apache server, my suggestion/answer below to use a proxy should work since webapp1 should be able to route traffic to/from webapp2 via localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, certainly, except you wouldn't include the contents of the second web app inside the war file of the first. Just use webapp1 as a proxy to webapp2. Try using this library in webapp1: https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet, and have it proxy to the localhost url (which should get you around the SSO depending on how that is setup) of webapp2.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Hi -- it's working, but I'm having problems with links.  `http://srv:port/webapp1/webapp2/` is showing the home page of webapp2. Great! The home page has a link on it like so: `<a href="showpage2">`, and that takes me to `http://srv:port/webapp1/webapp2/showpage2` which displays page2.  Great!  PROBLEM: page2 has a link on it like so: `<a href="showhome">, and that tries to go to `http://srv:port/webapp1/webapp2/showpage2/showhome` which does not exist.  I tried changing the link to `<a href="/showhome"> but that didn't work either.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Hi -- tagging you hoping you can help with my follow-up question in the comment above.  Thanks!

Comment: @RobertHume, you'll have to read up on html anchor tags and relative urls to master their behavior. From your description, the anchors are behaving as they are designed.